# Why can't I source from Bioconductor?

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

I tried to download packages RBGL, graph and RGraphviz from Bioconductor. However when I load the following code:

```
source('http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R')
biocLite(c("graph","RBGL","Rgraphviz"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(quote({ : unused argument (new.env())
Error: could not find function "biocLite"
```

Would anyone kindly help please?

Comment: This works for me, so the problem is specific to your particular R session or your local computer, thus we'd need more details to troubleshoot it.

Comment: It works for me too.

Comment: I'm guessing there was an initial error message from the first line that you have not given us. I'm getting "Bioconductor does not yet support R version 3.3.1"

Comment: I'm on 3.3.1 (Windows). Unrelated comment -- I haven't tried this myself, but you could try installing it via the `devtools` function `install_bioc`. Though there's probably some underlying problem with your setup that would be better to fix.

Comment: Recommend you provide your `sessionInfo()`